# How to convert a yml file to a text file?

Tags: python, yaml

I'm trying to convert a yml file to a text file.
This is my code:

```
#Import Modules
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
import yaml

#Read file
with open("/Users/AndreB/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Programming/Python/Tests/ymlProject/MOOCnlVersion1.yml", 'r') as stream:
    try:
        loaded = yaml.safe_load(stream)
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)

#File Url
file_read = "/Users/AndreB/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Programming/Python/Tests/ymlProject/MOOCnlVersion1.yml"

#Loop through file
for key, value in yaml.safe_load(open(file_read)).items():
    #Write file
    with open("YamlTextFileVersion1.txt", 'w') as stream:
        try:
            yaml.dump(loaded, stream, default_flow_style=False)
        except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
            print(exc)
```

The yaml file consists of more than 5000 lines.
This is part of the file:

```
course:
    courses:
      date:
        self_paced: Self-paced
        beginning: "Beginning %{start_date}"
        since: "Since %{start_date}"
        range: "%{start_date} - %{end_date}"
        coming_soon: Coming soon
      index:
        headline: "Our courses: smart. social. <span class='primary-color'>free.</span>"
        subheadline: "Join one of our free and open courses and be part of the social learning experience!"
        current: Current courses
        upcoming: Upcoming courses
        archive: Self-paced courses
        archive_text: Note that you can still enroll to finished courses and access them for self-learning (without the chance to earn a Record of Achievement).
        in_preparation: Courses in preparation (unpublished)
        partner_courses: Partner courses
        partner_courses_text: You might also want to have a look at these courses provided by our partners.
        hidden: Hidden Courses
```

But when I try to run the code, I get this error message:

```
Exception has occurred: ScannerError
while scanning a simple key
  in "/Users/AndreB/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Programming/Python/Tests/ymlProject/MOOCnlVersion1.yml", line 455, column 9
could not find expected ':'
  in "/Users/AndreB/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Programming/Python/Tests/ymlProject/MOOCnlVersion1.yml", line 456, column 9
  File "/Users/AndreB/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Programming/Python/Tests/ymlProject/TestConvertToTxt.py", line 20, in <module>
    for key, value in yaml.safe_load(open(file_read)).items():
```

Can someone help me?

Extra for @blurryroots
There are also lines in the yml file that should not be translated (indicated with "do not translate")

```
 news: # Do not translate
        title: News Statistics # Do not translate
        globaal: # Do not translate
          title: Globaal News # Do not translate
        course: # Do not translate
          title: Course Announcements # Do not translate
        news_title_header: News title # Do not translate
        course_title_header: Course title # Do not translate
        total_header: Total # Do not translate
        success_header: Success # Do not translate
        error_header: Error # Do not translate
        disabled_header: Disabled # Do not translate
        read_header: Read # Do not translate
        newest_header: Newest # Do not translate
        oldest_header: Oldest # Do not translate
        state_header: Status # Do not translate
        progress_header: Progress # Do not translate
        readstate_progress_header: ReadState Progress # Do not translate
        state_text: # Do not translate
          text_sending: sending # Do not translate
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It seems you basically just want to create a copy of the file with txt instead of yml as file extension. Also, the error states, that there seems to be a formatting error in the source yml file at line 455.

Comment: @blurryroots The code I showed is a small part of the code. In the long term I want to translate the entire yml file to another language. I thought the best way is to convert the yml file to a text file first.

Comment: By "another language" do you mean another markup language like XML/JSON or another spoken language like German/French?

Comment: There are specific "internationalization" libraries that allow you to write programs with support for multiple "spoken languages"

Comment: So you have a perfectly fine set of data, formatted in a well supported markup language like yaml, and you want to store it 'long-term' as an unstructured text file?

Comment: @blurryroots I mean a spoken language.

Comment: I agree with @blurryroots. Makes no sense to convert if from yaml to text. You could have multiple yaml files, one for each language that contains the translations. Then in your code you just load the relevant file for the user selected language and use the text from that file to be displayed to the user.

Comment: @blurryroots I want to convert it to a text file because there are lines in the yml file that should not be translated to a spoken language (indicated by a "# do not translate" in the file). I thought the best way to cut these lines is to first convert it to a txt file.

Comment: @scotty3785 I want to convert it to a text file because there are lines in the yml file that should not be translated to a spoken language (indicated by a "# do not translate" in the file). I thought the best way to cut these lines is to first convert it to a txt file.

Comment: The foreign language data has to be created and stored in a formatted fasion also, I assume. So the idea to abstract a common, language neutral set of data seems reasonable. Long term, it might make sense, to create a common data yaml file for an event, along-side a set of language specific files. So when you select an event, you just have to combine the common data with the language specific data. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: If you use one of the many internationalisation libraries that exist, they have methods of defaulting back to a "standard" language if a translation doesn't exist. Don't re-invent the wheel when you could just use an existing one. Have a read of https://docs.python.org/3/library/i18n.html

Comment: @blurryroots The whole idea is to translate a yml file to dutch. I thought of using the googletrans api. The yaml consists of more than 5000 lines, but there are lines that should not be translated (indicated with "do not translate")(I edited the question for clarity). After I translated all the lines except the lines that were not allowed to be translated I make a new yml file. This yml file consists of the lines that have just been translated and the lines that were not allowed to be translated. I hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a blacklist as the next iterative development step.

```yaml
event:
  news:
    field_to_ignore: true
```

When processing the event data to hand it over to translation (e.g. google translate API like you mentioned in your comment), you check if the field is contained in the the blacklist yaml. If so, simply skip. Otherwise translate.

Than you could simply store the translated data set for later lookup depending on the selected language.

Long term, it might be worth re-thinking the data structure and use already existing architectures and libraries, like [i18n](https://docs.python.org/3/library/i18n.html) pointed out by @scotty3785 in the comments. Properly separating common data, from language dependent data.

[This library](https://github.com/danhper/python-i18n) or [this article](https://www.mattlayman.com/blog/2015/i18n/) might bring you some inspiration on how to structure the data.